# Windows 8 and file association

Tags: windows, windows-8, images, file-association

It seems absurd but all my installed image viewers can't change file association in my new Windows 8. What I'm missing?

EDIT: summary,

- It is not that I can't change file association in my new Windows 8 at
  all.
- Doing in the Windows 8's way works. I am able to change all `.jpg` files to associate with the Windows Photo Viewer.
- But doing in the Windows 8's way is a PITA. I don't want to do this stupid thing again and again for gazillion of image file types, so I'm installing other image viewers to have them associate all image files at once.
- That's where things not working in my new Windows 8.

Long story,

In my new Windows 8, I found that image viewer is default to the photo app installed on the operating system.  Whenever I click on a image in File Explorer, I'm taken to the photo app that launches in full screen, and no easy way out.

So I went ahead and configure Windows to open all `.jpg` files with the Windows Photo Viewer desktop app instead of the Photos app. However, whenever I click on a `.gif` in File Explorer, I'm taken back to the photo app. This is really frustrating, why MS doesn't provide a way to associate all image files at once as always, but I have to do this stupid thing again and again for gazillion of image file types?

I don't want to do that, so I went ahead and install other image viewers. I ended up installing two,

http://en.softonic.com/s/windows-7-photo-viewer-download
http://www.xiles.net/nexusimage/

But found none of their file association is working with my new Windows 8. I.e., they both provide ways to associate all image files at once, and I've tried several times, but in the end the rest of image files are still associated with the stupid photo app.

Changing file association has never been a problem before, ever since windows 3.0, why in my new Windows 8, I can't do it anymore. What I'm missing?

I tried to find the answer myself,

http://informatives.net/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-8/
http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-change-file-associations-144102
http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57607585-285/the-new-features-you-need-to-know-about-in-windows-8.1/
http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/17/like-windows-8-1/
http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-81-tips

But I didn't find anything related to my problem. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: When you run those program, are you running them "As Administrator" so they're allowed to change the associations system-wide?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change all file type associations from one program to another](http://superuser.com/questions/41609/change-all-file-type-associations-from-one-program-to-another), also check out [Associating an editor to all text file extensions](http://superuser.com/questions/90282/associating-an-editor-to-all-text-file-extensions?rq=1)

Comment: Ahh, good call. Just tried, both, but neither works.

Comment: No it is not duplicate, both links you gave are from people who don't know how to do it, but my case is I know how to do it, ever since windows 3.0, but it doesn't work in my new Windows 8.

Comment: Did you try all the ways suggested in the various answers within those Questions?

Comment: I tried the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT export/import one. All else, are not much different than doing it from image viewers that I have, which provides that functionality. If that built-in functionality doesn't work, what do you think others, like Default Programs Editor for win7 will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows 8 you can set multiple extensions to be associated with a program in one shot.

- Search (in Windows) for "Default Programs", and open it.
- Select *Set your default programs*.
- In the list, find the app you want to associate extensions to and select it.
- Click *Choose defaults for this program*.
- A list of all known extensions will be presented.
- Select all extensions you wish to associate to the selected program.
- Click *Save*.

[image]

[Image source/more info](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-change-file-associations-144102)

Comment: thanks, that works. Much clearer than http://informatives.net/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-8/

Comment: Just want to point out that, in this method, the `.jpg` file that I had associated with the Windows Photo Viewer before using the method from http://informatives.net/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-8/, is never able to be ticked. I ticked it several times, but having saved and check back again, it will not be there. Tried several times.